# How to stop cron from running all daily tasks on startup

Tags: cron, startup

I noticed my computer is slow on startup sometimes, and using iotop it looks like cron's daily tasks (updatedb.mlocate in this case) run immediately on startup. If my conjecture is right, then I need to get cron to do its tasks at a more convenient time, or at least control its IO so that the rest of the system can run smoothly. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Check /var/log/syslog to test your conjecture. Anacron will run daily tasks, starting several *minutes* after boot, if over 24 hours have elapsed since the last time daily tasks were run. Or perhaps you are consistently starting your system a minute before daily tasks run anyway. Figure out the actual problem before leaning in to a solution.

Comment: @user535733 After having the chance to replicate this more over the last few days, it seems like the real issue is running immediately after coming out of hybernation rather than startup. Is this more plausible?